# Converting image into data:image/png;base64 for web page disaplay

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, image, encoding

If one visits [jQuery-File-Upload Demo page](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) and will try to upload an image, and then will look at the JSON response, he would notice that a preview of an uploaded image is returned in a format:

```
"thumbnail_url":"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAI...
```

As far as I understand, an images is getting transformed into string and sent back to the client.

How can I do it in C# to impelement ASP.NET back end for the same demo?

Comment: I remember an answer to a question that might be helpful to you from a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8706618/1073107

Comment: @dash - fantastic. Post it as an answer. It is only like two lines of code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I remember reading an answer to a question a while back by the very competent competent_tech and thinking "I never knew you could do that!"

[In that answer is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8706618/1073107) about how to set the src of an ASP.Net image to be the base64 encoded data you see above.

It effectively boils down to setting the src of an ASP:Image control as follows:

```
imgCtrl.Src = @"data:image/gif;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(@"/images/your_image.gif")));
```

Remember to change the content type depending on the image!

Comment: For those who might stumble into this thread:  if your image is generated as a memory stream, you can do something like:

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
/* {Then some code to populate that image stream } */
String base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

And then use the answer as described above.