# How to bind a MemoryStream to image control without using Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, bind, memorystream

I retrieve image from database and want to display in an  control.

The code:

```
MemoryStream str= new MemoryStream();
byte[] n = (byte[])db.imagefile;
str.Write(n, 0, db.imagefile.Length);
```

How can I bind a MemoryStream to an image control, without using a handler?

Comment: you can use data url with base64, for example [Should I embed images as data/base64 in CSS or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258057/should-i-embed-images-as-data-base64-in-css-or-html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting image into data:image/png;base64 for web page disaplay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728424/converting-image-into-dataimage-pngbase64-for-web-page-disaplay)

Comment: But the image is coming from database, not from a folder..@celerno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have byte array from database, so you just need to convert **byte array** to **Base64** encoded string.

Then assign the Base64 encoded string to **ImageUrl** of asp:Image control.

```
public class Database
{
    public byte[] Imagefile { get; set; }

    public Database()
    {
        // PNG Red dot
        Imagefile = new byte[]
        {
            137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,
            68,82,0,0,0,10,0,0,0,10,8,6,0,0,0,141,50,
            207,189,0,0,0,4,103,65,77,65,0,0,177,143,
            11,252,97,5,0,0,0,9,112,72,89,115,0,0,11,
            19,0,0,11,19,1,0,154,156,24,0,0,0,7,116,
            73,77,69,7,214,6,1,23,57,40,29,23,87,226,0,
            0,0,29,116,69,88,116,67,111,109,109,101,110,
            116,0,67,114,101,97,116,101,100,32,119,105,
            116,104,32,84,104,101,32,71,73,77,80,239,100,
            37,110,0,0,0,93,73,68,65,84,24,211,189,204,
            189,13,130,80,0,196,241,31,116,180,236,224,
            22,76,224,50,14,224,46,206,193,8,54,38,132,
            61,44,77,94,197,217,88,188,16,94,103,184,234,114,
            31,127,254,173,110,31,132,203,207,14,29,235,
            225,43,92,195,28,94,225,214,196,135,119,40,
            225,19,158,117,215,87,163,9,165,202,182,48,
            182,136,247,176,132,71,115,116,190,190,12,
            146,26,23,123,74,217,138,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,
            68,174,66,6,130
        };
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var db = new Database();

    Image1.ImageUrl = string.Concat("data:image/png;base64,",
        Convert.ToBase64String(db.Imagefile));
}
```

### Web browser support

As of March 2012, Data URIs are supported by the following web browsers:

- Gecko-based, such as Firefox, SeaMonkey, XeroBank, Camino, Fennec and K-Meleon
- Konqueror, via KDE's KIO slaves input/output system
- Opera (including devices such as the Nintendo DSi or Wii) WebKit-based, such as Safari (including iOS), Android's browser, Kindle 4's browser, Epiphany and Midori (WebKit is a derivative of Konqueror's KHTML engine, but Mac OS X does not share the KIO architecture so the implementations are different), and Webkit/Chromium-based, such as Chrome
- Trident

  - Internet Explorer 8: Microsoft has limited its support to certain "non-navigable" content for security reasons, including concerns that JavaScript embedded in a data URI may not be interpretable by script filters such as those used by web-based email clients. Data URIs must be smaller than 32 KB in Version 8.[3] Data URIs are supported only for the following elements and/or attributes:

    - object (images only)
    - img
    - input type=image
    - link
    - CSS declarations that accept a URL, such as background-image, background, list-style-type, list-style and similar.
  - Internet Explorer 9: Internet Explorer 9 does not have 32KB limitation and supports more elements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Web_browser_support

Comment: Please include information on the largest number of bytes that will fit such a URL.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you for reminding. I added the information.

Comment: It Works.. I just don't quite understand  why do we write this statement here: "data:image/png;base64,". Can you please explain? Thanks you so much. @Win

Comment: @perlynsparks Basically, it is the way of saying to browser that the data is a png image encoded as base64. You can read more [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format).