# How can i send email from c# that contain graphics as dygraph js does?

Tags: c#, email-client, razorengine

I need to send email report from c# code. This email contain graphic like the image. is there any way to make that in c#?
[dygraph graphic must be included in the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooqh0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to construct the email, and the [SmtpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to send the message. You'll need to set up the SmtpClient appropriately*.

In order to embed an image, you need to set the email to be HTML, and include an alternate view with the embedded image:

```
var mail = new MailMessage();
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

var inline = new LinkedResource(@"C:\path\to\your\image.png");
inline.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var htmlBody = @"<img src='cid:" + inline.ContentId + @"'/>"; // Include whatever other content in the html body here.
var alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(inline);

mail.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);
```

Then set the to/from/subject fields and use the [SmtpClient.Send Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (or SendAsync) to send the email.

*From the MSDN docs:

To construct and send an e-mail message by using SmtpClient, you must specify the following information:

- The SMTP host server that you use to send e-mail. See the Host and Port properties.
- Credentials for authentication, if required by the SMTP server. See the Credentials property.
- The e-mail address of the sender. See the Send and SendAsync methods that take a from parameter. Also see the MailMessage.From property.
- The e-mail address or addresses of the recipients. See the Send and SendAsync methods that take a recipient parameter. Also see the MailMessage.To property.
- The message content. See the Send and SendAsync methods that take a body parameter. Also see the MailMessage.Body property.

Comment: I need to generate the image(graphics, chart), i mean. the problem is how generate the charts and sent by email. i understan that i can send images. but how generate the chart and make it an image..

I have a background worker that runs 24/7 on a number of servers and send a email; before send the email i must generate a chart with DB data  and this must be included in the email.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Do you have something that's generating these charts already? If so, you can use an HttpClient or something to get the image, and then do a Base64 encoding or something like in Ollie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Dotnet contains a [MailMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.%23ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) class with an [IsBodyHtml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.IsBodyHtml);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property. You can construct your email message using a text string. Into the text string, write HTML with an `<img ..>` tag pointing to the graphic.

You can insert the datastream for the image directly into the image tag using the [data: URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), with tags that don't refer to external images. That looks something like this.

```
img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG==" />
```

You can do this by following the advice here.  [Converting image into data:image/png;base64 for web page disaplay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728424/converting-image-into-dataimage-pngbase64-for-web-page-disaplay)