# Load generated image into asp image control wihtout saving it physically

Tags: c#, asp.net, zxing

I'm trying to load an image into an asp image control.
That image is generated from zxing Barcode Writter.
My question is, can I load it wihtout physically saving it first?

```
string barcode = "xxxxxx";
BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128 };

imgBarCode.ImageUrl = writer.Write(barcode);
```

... How can I reference writer.Writer to image control "imgBarCode"

Comment: What type does the `Write` method return? If you can get the actual image bytes out of the `BarcodeWriter` instance, then you can `Base64` encode it and construct a data URI out of it. This can then be used as the source/imageurl on the image control. See (for instance) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9728424/1429080)

Comment: @user1429080 it returns a bitmap, as you said saved it in a memory stream, converted to base64 string and done.
edit:
thx mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the suggestion made by user1429080 I ended up with this:

```
string barcode = "12345"

BarcodeWriter writer = new BarcodeWriter() { Format = BarcodeFormat.CODE_128, Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions { Height = 100, Width = 300 } };

var bitmap = writer.Write(barcode);    
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
var b64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());

imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + b64;
```

Comment: Nice that you got it working. One thing though: If that is the actual code, then you should likely have a look at each object you are using and check which ones are `IDisposable`. Make sure to dispose them after you are done with them...

Comment: Thx, for reminding me!
I .Dispose() them at the end.