# Send an email which has embedded images (Base64) using c#

Tags: c#, email, bitmap, base64

```
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(data.photoBase64);

            var imageMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            Image imageFromStream = Image.FromStream(imageMemoryStream);


            oMail.HtmlBody = "<html><body><b> Maintenance, Repair and Operationa </b><br>S/N : " + data.serial + 
              
                " <br>Image: "+ imageFromStream + "</body></html>";
```

I want to send e-mail image in base64 format data, but when I already send email it returns the following result.

[image: I want to send e-mail image in base64 format data, but when I already send email it returns the following result.]

Comment: This actually doesn't have anything to do with e-mail. You're trying to include the C# object in the e-mail rather than the base64-encoded image contents (`bytes`). You'll probably also need the HTML image tag and the correct prefix for the data.

Comment: I don't know how to send image data. Would you recommend it to me?

Comment: I'd start by finding out how embedded images work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9728424/converting-image-into-dataimage-pngbase64-for-web-page-disaplay

Comment: I tried sending it as base64 but it is not support in outlook.